# Android dynamic layouts and state save/restore

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In a new activity I am writing I want to dynamically layout and populate part of the layout.

What I have so far is a main layout with an empty layout element (say a LinearLayout). And I have a layout file for an element of dynamic content (lets say a LinearLayout containing a Spinner and 2 buttons with their own id's).

I can inflate the dynamic content elements fine, and add them into the LinearLayout. And by calling findViewbyId on the inflated LinearLayout I can get references to the UI elements I need for any events etc (e.g. setOnClickListener).

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.my_dynamic_content_layout_id);
//Might actually inflate a number of different things, but for simplicity...
ViewGroup newContent = (ViewGroup)View.inflate(this, R.layout.dynamic_content_element, null);
group.addView(newContent);

((Button)newContent.findViewById(R.id.my_button)).setButtonListener(...);
```

The problem comes however in getting my dynamic content to persist when the activity is recreated (e.g. orientation change). I added some data in onSaveInstanceState so that I can reinflate the views I need, but it seems because of the duplicated id's in the dynamic content that Android messes up the state of the individual UI widgets (at some point after onCreate is finished), setting the state of every element with a given id to be that of the last occurrence in the ui tree when onSaveInstanceState was called...

I think I need to do more in onSaveInstanceState / onCreate to save/restore everything needed myself. However before I go figure out how to save/restore individual widgets into a Bundle, and likely run into a load of harder issues todo with preserving which element has input focus etc...

Is there a better way to be doing this, like some method on a layout to save/load in respect to its tree structure instead (e.g. a get Bundle[] from a ViewGroup contain an element for each child in order) that works pretty much like the default implementation (e.g. nearly completely automatic) but handles the duplicated id's/layouts properly?